# Unable to access analog pins (Arduino Mega, pyfirmata)

Tags: python, arduino, pyfirmata

I'm trying to read some values from analog joystick using my Arduino Mega 2560 board. Since I intend to use my Arduino in a bigger Python project, I am using pyfirmata to write the code. However, I am unable to access all of my analog pins, which the Mega has 16 in total. After declaring my board etc.:

```
board = pyfirmata.Arduino('COM8')
iterator = pyfirmata.util.Iterator(self.board)
iterator.start()
```

the statement `print(len(board.analog))` returns value of 6 and upon trying to access a pin with index 6 or higher, I get the following error: `IndexError: list index out of range`. However, when I attempt to read values from those pins by code written in Arduino IDE and not using pyfirmata, everything is in order. So I am wondering if pyfirmata is somehow misinterpreting my board and I should perhaps declare that I am in fact using Mega, which has 16 analog pins, not 6 as it seems to think.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are instructions on the pyFirmata home page that tells you how to configure it for various configurations.  You need to use `pyfirmata.ArduinoMega`, not `Arduino`.

https://pypi.org/project/pyFirmata/

Comment: Can't believe I missed that. Everything works now, thanks a lot :)